# For each string in column calculate average (second column)

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a section of my dataset (for example flavours of ice cream and their ratings):

| flavor | rating |
| --- | --- |
| cherry, apple, flower | 4.0 |
| apple, chocolate, banana | 3.0 |
| banane, chocolate, strawberry | 4.0 |
| cherry, banane, strawberry | 1.0 |

Now I want to calculate the average rating of the flavours.
So that I get following output:

| flavor | avg(rating) |
| --- | --- |
| cherry | 2.5 |
| apple | 3.5 |
| banane | 2.66 |
| strawberry | 2.5 |
| chocolate | 3.5 |
| flower | 4.0 |

How can I approach this in mysql?

Comment: Please tag your specific RDBMS

Comment: Normalize your schema. See ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) (Spoiler: Yes, it is.).

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the big issue here would be to split the data into separate rows, as answered in https://stackoverflow.com/q/17942508/2422776 . From there on, you can group by the flavor and query the average.

Answer (score 1):

```
with recursive u as
(select 1 as n
union all select n + 1 from u
where n < (select max(length(flavor) - length(replace(flavor, ',', ''))) + 1 
from ice_cream)),
v as
(select
  LTRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ice_cream.flavor, ',', u.n), ',', -1)) 
single_flavor,
ice_cream.rating
from
  u inner join ice_cream
  on CHAR_LENGTH(ice_cream.flavor)
  -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(ice_cream.flavor, ',', ''))>=u.n-1
)
(select single_flavor, avg(rating) from v group by single_flavor);
```

`u` gets you a table with the numbers 1, 2, ..., max number of single flavours in a row. `v` makes use of `u` to split every row in the original table into single flavours and their rating, and the last cte just groups rows from `v` by single flavour and calculates the average rating for each flavour.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2060b9510a28b48e6da9e3d36bc5f4fe)

Comment: @jarlh citing OP: "How can I approach this in mysql?"

Comment: Oops, I didn't see that last sentence. Anyway, I have now approved your edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query

```
select flavor,avg(rating)
from 
 
  (select
    tablename.rating,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tablename.flavor, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) flavor
  from
    (select 1 n union all
     select 2 union all select 3 union all
     select 4 union all select 5) numbers INNER JOIN tablename
    on CHAR_LENGTH(tablename.flavor)
       -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(tablename.flavor, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1) t

group by flavor
```

Demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=74de132d5ae01420e8db290e4b904132)

Take a look at this link [SQL split values to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17942691/15019536)